# angularjs override ng-init value by placeholder value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-init, ng-init

I have the following input:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your response" class="form-control" name="response" ng-model="test.response" ng-init="test.response='No Response'"/>
```

it is showing "no response" in the input text area, whereas I want to show the placeholder value. How can I override it? hide the ng-init value?
thanks

Comment: Yes, just remove the ng-init value if you want it to stay null

Comment: Placeholder is show only if your input model is blank. Therefore you need to  assign value 'No response' to your test.response only on form submit

Comment: @AnthonyGranger i want to pass the ng-init value if no response is given instead of passing a null value.

Comment: You're setting a value via the `ngInit` and you want to keep it that way and  wonder how to still show the placeholder. It's like ordering hot dog and complaining that you want a burger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use ng-init.

If you want to pass 'No Response' instead of null then check condition on submit

for ex.

```
$scope.submitForm = function(){
  if(!test.response){
     test.response='No Response';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it showing "No Response" it is because the value of the input is "No response". If you want to show the placeholder, remove the ng-init :)

Comment: i don't want to remove the ng-init value, because i don't want to pass `null` value when no response is given. I want to pass `No Response`instead. that is why i chose to include it.

Comment: On the function where you submit the form, check if the value of this is null. If null set the value to "No Response"